# How can I add a foreign key when creating a new table?

Tags: mysql, create-table

I have these two `CREATE TABLE` statements:

```
CREATE TABLE GUEST (
  id int(15) not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  GuestName char(25) not null
);

CREATE TABLE PAYMENT (
  id int(15) not null auto_increment
  Foreign Key(id) references GUEST(id),
  BillNr int(15) not null
);
```

What is the problem in the second statement? It did not create a new table.

Comment: You might want to replace Foriegn by Foreign for starters ;)

Answer (score 13):

The answer to your question is almost the same as the answer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236668/foreign-keys-in-mysql#236677) .

You need to specify in the table containing the foreign key the name of the table containing the primary key, and the name of the primary key field (using "references").

[This](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) has some code showing how to create foreign keys by themselves, and in CREATE TABLE.

Here's one of the simpler examples from that:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (id INT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE child (id INT, parent_id INT,
   INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 8):

I will suggest having a unique key for the payment table.  On it's side, the foreign key should not be auto_increment as it refer to an already existing key.

```
CREATE TABLE GUEST(
    id int(15) not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
    GuestName char(25) not null
)  ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE PAYMENT(
    id int(15)not null auto_increment, 
    Guest_id int(15) not null, 
    INDEX G_id (Guest_id), 
    Foreign Key(Guest_id) references GUEST(id),
    BillNr int(15) not null
)  ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the InnoDB engine for either the database, or for both tables. From the MySQL Reference:

> For storage engines other than InnoDB,
>   MySQL Server parses the FOREIGN KEY
>   syntax in CREATE TABLE statements, but
>   does not use or store it.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table course(ccode int(2) primary key,course varchar(10));

create table student1(rollno int(5) primary key,name varchar(10),coursecode int(2) not 
null,mark1 int(3),mark2 int(3),foreign key(coursecode) references course(ccode));
```

Answer (score -1):

There should be space between `int(15)` and `not null`