# Why won't this table creation work in mysql

Tags: mysql

I do not know why this simple table will not create itself when ran 
it just says there is a problem with the closing bracket

```
CREATE TABLE LeaderBoard (
ID INT,
Score int,
PRIMARY KEY (ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: Foreign key to what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use foreign key into new table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239443/how-to-use-foreign-key-into-new-table)

Comment: Read the error message closely: _check the manual ... for the right syntax to use **near** ')' at line 6_ - the problem is not with the bracket itself but with the section immediately before that. MySQL encountered the bracket when it is expecting details to be provided about the foreign key.

Comment: the foreign key is a unique identifier for a different also called id table

Comment: Perhaps you should review this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys must reference some other table.

A foreign key is a value that references a row in another table through its primary key, used to establish a relation between the two tables. In other words, a column declared as foreign key must contain values picked from some other table's primary key column (if it has more than one, there should be a foreign key column for each primary key column in the reference table).

It makes no sense to declare a foreign key without referencing another table.

I recommend you read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

(NOTE: some engines might relax some of the restrictions I outlined above; I don't remember MySQL's exact limitations in the matter. Notwithstanding, it's important that you understand the concept of foreign keys and relations before designing a database schema.)