# mySQL - Web application only with private users

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am attempting to make a web app, where there is a login system and then once you have logged in you can add things to your personal list.

I'm new to mySQL and website creation, so I'm a little confused on how to do this.

I need a user database:

```
users
id username name   email            password 
1  john123  john   john@gmail.com   password
2  jenna23  jenna  jenna@gmail.com  password3
```

But I also need a database the hold the data of the users.

John's data looks like this:

```
item-name type   image
cat      animal  cat.jpg
cheeto   food    cheeto.jpg
```

But Jenna's data looks like:

```
item-name type   image
dog      animal  dog.jpg
grapes   food    grapes.jpg
```

I don't plan on the users being able to share data with each other like a blog post type system at least at this point. Right now I just want users to be use this site as a way to store their personal items.

Should each user have their own table? Or should I just put all of their data in one database, but couldn't that mess up somehow?

Comment: You should use a single table for the date, but it should have a column that contains the `id` (primary key) that denotes the user who "owns" each row in the data table.

Comment: You'll want to look into [foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). There's no need to create a separate database table for each user. You can check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236668/foreign-keys-in-mysql) for some examples.